# VSCode shortcut key to show file in explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut key to show/focus on a file on the left side of the file explorer?

I know the ctrl-shift-E shortcut key to focus on the explorer "tab" (not a specific file), but this is not what I need.

Is there a builtin or third-party way to achieve this?

Comment: You want to split the editor with two files?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings check this out you may find it in here

Comment: No not splitting. The situation I have is that I have a tons of files on the project (django or rails), like 200 or 300 files, many dirs. when I want to check dir structure of a dir or create a new file or folder, or drag and drop a folder to a certain dir, I need first reveal the file or dir's whereabouts. so I need a shortcut key or command for this.

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+0` (zero)

Comment: ctrl+0 is good. But I'm looking for a way to... well, "search" a file. (sorry I guess I should have include this to the original question). Not right clicking a file nor shortcut key to reveal the current file or current selected file. As you can search files to open, ability to search files to reveal is also a good thing I think, I mean.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> is what my VSCode says

[image]

You might also need to remove extra stuff

[image]

Comment: I cannot see that "reveal in file exploror" command in the ctrl-shift-p command palette. Is that something you see on a context menu when you right click a file somewhere?

Comment: If you right click a file it shows that

Comment: I'm looking for a way to reveal a file on the explorer when there are too many files that you don't want to locate its file location. sorry for my poor explanation above.